# x11 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11' - Unable to run Kivy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pycharm, kivy

I am trying to run a Kivy app in Pycharm but keep getting the following error:

```
    /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/mark/PycharmProjects/KivyExample/venv/main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/mark/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-02-26_18.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3.6"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - ImportError: libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

x11 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I have tried every suggestion and answer in similar threads but have been unsuccessful. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: »» libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0: ... No such file or directory «« : Install the package `libsdl2-image-2.0-0`

Comment: The requirements that need to be installed are listed [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux-venvs.html#dependencies-with-sdl2).

Answer (score 1):

To fix, install the requirements found [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux-venvs.html#dependencies-with-sdl2).

Big thanks to John Anderson for the help!